# Blender hair particles shape. Change to ribbon

Tags: modeling, particles

Using blender 2.79. In earlier versions of blender in particles settings i'm using ribbon particles shape, but in 2.79 i'm unable change hair particles shape to flat ribbon. Why this option removed?

One way to do this is create flat ribbon object and using it to render object? Right?

Maybe there is some other way?

**Old blender dialog**

[image]

**New blender dialog**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this!

This setting is now in render tab - geometry section.

[image]